# Read user country on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, country-codes, mobile-country-code

How I can read the user country code on windows phone.
I need to know his country not the language of the phone.

For example if the user is from Austria or from Germany the language of the phone usually is German, but I need a way to rad this difference. I don't want to access the user gps location since I need only the country.

Edit1:
I have found out that you don't have access to the mcc/mnc to map them to a country code. You can vote this feature request [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3700140-allow-access-to-mcc-and-mnc-of-sim-and-network)

Answer (score 0):

I have soled this problem using

```
var region = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion;
```

From [GlobalizationPreferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences.aspx#properties) class